# Can an artificer have a steel defender and a homunculus?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

Thinking about playing an artificer character and curious about the interactions with the Steel defender and the homunculus servant infusion, is there any contraindication?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You can have both a Homunculus Servant and a Steel Defender.

There's nothing that prevents an artificer with the Steel Defender feature to also choose the Homunculus Servant as one of their infusion known and make use of it.
    The only mechanic you have "against" you is: you only get one bonus action on each of your turns; therefore you can only give a command to either your Steel Defender or your Homunculus Servant on your turn but not both.